# How to return something after removing it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `$(selector).remove();` in jQuery to remove some elements, and want to be able to return those after I deleted them.

How can I return them when they are removed?

My code:

```
$("#cir1").click(function(){
   $("#cir2").fadeOut(100);
   $("#cir2").remove();
   $("#con2").fadeOut(100);
   $("#cir3").fadeOut(100);
   $("#cir3").remove();
   $("#con3").fadeOut(100);
   $("#cir4").fadeOut(100);
   $("#cir4").remove();
   $("#con4").fadeOut(100);
   $("#cir1").animate({
      width:'590px',
      height:'590px',
      borderRadius:'800px',
      left:'-2px',
      top:'-3.5px',
   });
   $(".matt").fadeOut(100);
   $("#con1").fadeOut(100);
   $("#abcon").fadeIn(300);
});
$("#back").mouseenter(function(){
   $("#cir1").animate({
      width:'195px',
      height:'195px',
      borderRadius:'100px',
   });

   $(".matt").fadeIn(100);
   $("#abcon").fadeOut(300);
   $("#cir2").fadeIn(100);
   $("#cir3").fadeIn(100);    
   $("#cir4").fadeIn(100);  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead.

```
var element = $("#cir3").detach();

// stuff

element.appendTo('#something');
```

Comment: tnx but I Dont UnderStand that when i use detach(); how to return ?
Its work And Remove Cir3 But I Want to Return Back cir3 when mouse enter the #back @adeneo

Comment: @Amirsina23 Why don't you simply use `hide()` and `show()` then?

Comment: If you remove the element, you have to append it back again, `detach` keeps all the data associated to the element, and creates a reference you can use to append it back, like in the code above. If it's just a hover effect it would seem a lot easier to just hide and show it.